# DateTimeInvalidLocalFormat occurred

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I am trying to get the local datetime with reference to UTC time gap and I am executing this code below.

```
 var dtString =DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fzzz");
```

but every time it return me an exception as

[image]

Why this exception is there, how to get this fixed?

Comment: Have you looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms172213 ?

Comment: It is not an exception, it is just a debugger warning.  Press F5 to continue.  If you don't want to see it then use Debug > Exceptions > Managed Debugging Assistants > untick the DateTimeInvalidLocalFormat option.  Do fret a bit about generating a nonsense string, a UTC date of course does not have a UTC offset.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, got it, stupid me didn't thought of UTC date and offset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `z` format specifier is used to show the offset between local time and UTC time.

It does not make sense to use it with the UTC time (since it is always 0). That is why you get a warning (thanks to @HansPassant for this remark).

You can either:

Want to print the local time and the offset to the UTC (**which is standard**):

```
var dtString = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.f zzz");
```

Or want to print the UTC time and the local time zone (which is **REALLY** not common):

```
var dtString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.f") + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString(@"zzz");
```

Which is more or less equivalent to your code (as explained in @JeroenMostert [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms172213)):

```
var dtString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fzzz");
```

But the resulting string is **not standard at all** and lead to misinterpretation.

```
"2015-02-18T12:08:15.1 +01:00"
```

Is read as *local time* and *local time zone*, not *UTC time* and *local time zone*.

Also you can find more information about time zone and good examples here : [TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Just had this issue on an old project targeting .NET 4.6 and 8. Funnily, it works as expected (adding "+00:00" to the string) in .NET 8. Somebody must have told them that they don't make sense.

Answer (score -3):

The full message text will probably answer your question:

> This can happen when calling DateTime.ToString using the 'z' format
>   specifier, which will include a local time zone offset in the output.
>   In that case, either use the 'Z' format specifier, which designates a
>   UTC time, or use the 'o' format string, which is the recommended way
>   to persist a DateTime in text.

Your format string contains the `z` specifier `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fzzz"`.  Try changing it to `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fZZZ"`.

Comment: That will just yield "ZZZ" in the string. The message is slightly misleading; "Z" isn't really a format specifier, but a single "Z" at the end (which is passed through unchanged) designates a UTC time.